# Different ways of creating intervals in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, intervals

I've recently come across this way of using the `interval` type in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1' month;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2018-11-22 00:00:00
```

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html), it looks like the “proper” way to do it would be:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2018-11-22 00:00:00
```

Are the two queries equivalent? Where's the former syntax documented?

Comment: The first one is standard SQL. The second one is PostgreSQL extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax is SQL standard syntax:

> ```
> <interval literal> ::= INTERVAL [ <sign> ] <interval string> <interval qualifier>
>
> <interval qualifier> ::=
>     <start field> TO <end field>
>   | <single datetime field>
> ```

I'll spare you the definition of `<start field>`, `<end field>` and `<single datetime field>`, but essentially they can take the values `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `MINUTE` or `SECOND`.

PostgreSQL doesn't support the `<sign>`, you'd have to add that to the string.

Here a few samples:

```
INTERVAL '1-10' YEAR TO SECOND
INTERVAL '20:03:15' DAY TO SECOND
INTERVAL '1' DAY
```